# django south migration - app migration is not in south_migration table

Tags: django, django-south

I have added a new app to my django application. The app has its migration scripts. When I run migration it says nothing to migrate. But when I look at the south_migration table it doesn't have a record. Yet all the other apps have record.

I also see database is acting bit strange. What do I need to do to get south_migration to have a record of my apps migration.

Comment: Have you added the new app to your INSTALLED_APPS setting? Is there a __init__.py file in the new app's directory?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you got this particular app in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Make sure app has folder and file `migrations/__init__.py` and of course migrations. (It seems that you've done that)

Also you can try resetting the app by doing (careful, it will remove tables in db):

`./manage.py migrate app_name zero`

To answer your last question: South saves migration history in db only after you run:

`./manage.py migrate app_name`